# htmlentities() dosen't seem to be working

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm using Atom to code, and I'm learning PHP, and going through `htmlentities()`. But in my example, it doesn't seem to change my apostrophes or `<>`  into their respective entities numbers... any chance someone knows what I'm doing wrong? either with the code or the Atom program settings?

code:

```
  <?php

    $str = "Une 'apostrophe' et une balise <strong>";

    echo htmlentities($str)."<br>";

    echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)."<br>";

  ?>
```

current results:

```
Une 'apostrophe' et une balise <strong>
Une 'apostrophe' et une balise <strong>
```

Expected results:

```
Une 'apostrophe' et une balise &lt;strong&gt
Une &#039;apostrophe&#039; et une balise &lt;strong&gt
```

Comment: You are probably viewing your output in a web browser so the browser is converting `&#039;` back into an apostrophe. Check the source code of your web page and you should see that everything was converted properly. https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/how-to-view-source-code-on-a-web-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the results.

The results I get when I run it:

> ```
> Une 'apostrophe' et une balise &lt;strong&gt;<br>Une &#039;apostrophe&#039; et une balise &lt;strong&gt;<br>
> ```

[image: screenshot]

Presumably, you are testing it by looking at the output in a web browser. The job of a web browser is to interpret the HTML, so it takes `&lt;` et al and converts them back to `<` for display. You can tell it worked there because you see `<strong>` rendered on screen instead of making the content after it appear in **bold formatting**.

Use the View Source feature of your browser to see the raw output.

Comment: Oh thanks, had no idea it was rendering automatically.